# Using List Comprehension to look up single values in a Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

I'm trying to essentially filter values in a dataframe which looks like this.
The user will pass in a list of Symbols and i'd like to return the corresponding MarketCaps  in a list for example. I know you can use .isin() to return a series and then convert the values to a list but Im wondering if theres not a better way to do this.

Shouldn't my list comprehension attempt be able to accomplish this?

I've tried this:

```
tickers = pd.read_csv('NASDAQcompanylist.csv')
stocks_list = ['AAPL','GOOG']
print(tickers.head())
x=stocks_list
y= tickers[tickers['Symbol']==stocks_list]['MarketCap']
```

I've also tried:

```
y=[tickers['Symbol'][stock]['MarketCap'] for stock in stocks_list]
```

Expected output for y would be:
(market caps of AAPL and GOOG)

```
[85436200000000,7001920000000]
```

Dataframe head is here.

```
  Symbol  ...                                 Industry
0   ABMD  ...               Medical/Dental Instruments
1   ATVI  ...  Computer Software: Prepackaged Software
2   ADBE  ...  Computer Software: Prepackaged Software
3    AMD  ...                           Semiconductors
4   AGNC  ...            Real Estate Investment Trusts
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set `Symbol` as your index (it makes sense, it's a unique identifier), then use it with `.loc` to get that row.

try:

```py
tickers = pd.read_csv('NASDAQcompanylist.csv').set_index('Symbol')
stocks_list = ['AAPL','GOOG']
y=[tickers.loc[stock,'MarketCap'] for stock in stocks_list]
```

**EDIT:** after comment, also a solution using `.isin()`:

```py
y = tickers[tickers.Symbol.isin(stocks_list)]["MarketCap"].tolist()
```

Comment: note: `.isin` is a much better way to do it then any list comprehension. pandas native library function are highly optimized and perform much better than pure python code.

Comment: Unfort I can't change the dataframe b/c it'll be different depending on the use case. It might already have an index that I wont be able to overwrite

Comment: @novawaly edited my answer with a `.isin` based solution